# Tengo un problema en C con strcmp

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que hay 6 claves definidas, al momento de usar strcmp me arroja resultados inesperados.

claves definidas:

```
char claves[10][10]={"420sku\0", "cripi6\0", "clave22\0", "vamo87\0", "bien33\0"};
```

función para verificar si la clave existe o no:

```
void clavesv(){
    char claveprueba[20][20];
    printf("Ingrese una contrasena\n");
    scanf ("%s", &claveprueba);
    for (i; i<5; i++) {
        if (strcmp(claves[i], claveprueba)==0){
            printf("Su clave existe\n");

        }else {
            if (strcmp(claves[i], claveprueba)==1){
            printf("Su clave no existe\n");
        }
        }
}
}
```

He intentado muchas cosas, pero me sigue arrojando varios resultados (su clave es incorrecta, su clave es correcta), en lugar de darme uno solo, si es correcta o no. Destaco que las claves son variables globales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te complicas demasiado, aparte de que no estás declarando las cosas correctamente:

```
char claveprueba[20][20];
```

¿ Una formación de 20 cadenas, cada una de ellas de 20 caracteres ? ¿ Para qué ?

```
scanf ("%s", &claveprueba);
```

Las formaciones *decaen* a punteros; te sobra el `&`.

```
for( ) {
  if( ) {
  }else {
    if( ) {
    }
  }
}
```

¿ Toda esa estructura anidada para comparar una cadena y mostrar un mensaje ? ¿ No te parece excesivo ? Y puesto que nunca *interrumpes* el `for( )`, te mostrará 5 mensajes cada vez, encuentres o no la clave que buscas.

Tu código, con algunos cambios:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE( ARR ) ( sizeof( ARR ) / sizeof( ARR[0] ) )

// El compilador sabe contar, no hay que indicar tamaños, ni poner el \0
static const char *claves[] = { "420sku", "cripi6", "clave22", "vamo87", "bien33" };

void clavesv( void ) {
  char entrada[20] = { 0 }; // Lo rellenamos con 0

  printf( "Ingrese una contrasena\n" );
  scanf( "%s", entrada );

  int idx;
  // Recorremos las claves.
  // Salimos del bucle si alguna coincide.
  for( idx = 0; ( idx < ARRAYSIZE( claves ) ) && strcmp( claves[idx], entrada ); ++idx );

  // Si recorrimos TODAS las claves, es que no la encontramos.
  if( idx == ARRAYSIZE( claves ) ) {
    printf( "Clave NO existe\n" );
  } else {
    printf( "Clave EXISTE en la posición %d\n", idx );
  }
}

int main( void ) {
  clavesv( );

  return 0;
}
```

Al usar `sizeof( )`, podemos cambiar el tamaño de la formación `claves[]` sin necesidad de tocar el código: el compilador sabe el tamaño, y nuestro `for( )` se adaptará sin problemas.

Comment: buena forma de inicializar el arreglo, complemento: para limpiar el arreglo, ya con el proceso en ejecución, usar memset(entrada,0x0,sizeof(entrada)), muy buen código

Comment: ¡ Gracias ! Se hace lo que se puede :-)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Soy nuevo programando, por eso tengo tantos problemas. Me sirvió mucho tu respuesta y me ayudó a comprender los errores que tengo!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a hacer lo siguiente:

```
void clavesv(){
    char claveprueba[20];
    printf("Ingrese una contrasena\n");
    scanf ("%s", &claveprueba);
    int encontrada=0;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        if (strcmp(claves[i], claveprueba)==0){
            encontrada=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (encontrada==1){
        printf("Su clave existe\n");

    }else {
        printf("Su clave no existe\n");
    }

}
```